# How to get "http://localhost:3000/users/current" from user_path(:current)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to practice [#163 Self-Referential Association](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association?view=asciicast) using **`Rails 3.2.21`** and work fine almost, but I can only display

`http://localhost:3000/users/1`

rather than

`http://localhost:3000/users/current`

in URL address bar. I read and search almost all code, I only find one `current`:

[<%= link_to "View Profile", user_path(:current) %>](https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes/blob/master/episode-163/friends/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb#L15).

What should I do for this? It is relative to `Rails 3`? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Railscast is a little unconventional, but the user_path() method, will take in a value (object, string, int, symbol) and call `to_param` on it.  A symbol (in this case :current) will turn into "current" and the url built will be "/users/current".  If you pass it a @user (User instance), the to_param method will return a "1" (the id of the object) giving you "/users/1".

I say this code is unconventional because the users_controller#show method doesn't use the ID to find the @user.  It just sets it to current_user for convenience.  Ryan was not trying to teach this necessarily, more about the restful friendship controller and data-modeling friendships.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot the method `to_param`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= link_to "View Profile", users_path(:current) %>.
```

Comment: @@Nitin  I got "http://localhost:5500/users.current" and did not display the content of "http://localhost:5500/users/1"

Comment: the `users_path` method doesn't need a parameter.  If there is one, it's the format (usually nil, but could be .html, .js, .xml, etc.)